# Non-Type Template Parameters [Bool operator overloading]

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I was wondering if there is any way of doing something like this:

```
     Template<class T, int node_1, int node_2>
     class Node_
     {
       private:
         //stuff goes here
       public:
       bool operator==(const Node<T,node_1,node_2> &rhs) const
       {
         //stuff goes here.
       }

**Test.cpp**

    #include "Node.h"
    //all includes 

    template <int node_1, int node_2>
    using NodeD = Node<double, node_1, node_2>;



     void test_it_by_comparing()
     {
      using NodeDRC = NodeD<node_1, node_2>; 
      using NodeDCR = NodeD<node_2, node_1>; 

    //observe position of non-type node_1 and node_2.

      using NodeD0 = NodeD<0, 0>;
      constexpr int node_1 = 2;
      constexpr int node_2 = 4;
      double v=1.;
      assert("compare check"&& !(NodeDCR(v) == NodeDRC(v)));
      assert("compare check" && NodeD0(0) != NodeDRC(v));
      assert("compare check" && !(NodeD0(0) == NodeDRC(v)));
     }
```

It is forcing me to implement different number of same operator to accept appropriate type because `node_1` and `node_2` template parameters switch positions.

I would appreciate if anyone can solve this issue.

Comment: You are probably looking for a templated `operator==` - something like `template <int node_1_other, int node_2_other> bool operator==(const Node<T, node_1_other, node_2_other>& other) const;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have that one implemented in public section of class

Comment: No, you have a non-template operator that can only compare two classes with the same set of parameters.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean & it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can template the `operator ==` to accomplish what you desire:

```
template<int M1, int M2>
bool operator ==(Node<T,M1,M2> const& rhs) const
{
    // whatever you want
}
```

Keep in mind this means any `Node<T,N1,N2>` can be compared against any arbitrary `Node<T,M1,M2>`. Only `T` is mandated the same for both lhs and rhs arguments. Alternatively, if you desire a guaranteed only argument flip you can specialize, but I doubt you need it.